# Projector resolution

Tags: video, resolution, hdmi, vga

This may be a stupid question but I was looking to buy a projector and I was looking at the different resolution options.

Then I started to read more about resolution. I came to this image on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2K_resolution#/media/File:Vector_Video_Standards8.svg) I see where 1080p is located and also 4K resolution but in between these two resolution levels are a bunch of others.

But when I look at different projector options all I see are projectors with 1080p and the more expensive newer 4K resolutions. So my question is are the resolutions shown in the Wiki image, those higher than 1080p but lower than 4k used in projectors? Just curious, if not, then what are these other resolutions used for?

Comment: Q: What are you going to use the projector for? I already touched in in my attemp to answer, but if it is movies then do not bother with 4k yet. There simply is not enough real 4k content yet.

Comment: If you only see 1080p projectors, you’re probably not looking hard enough. ;) For office purposes, cheaper lower-resolution projectors are still readily available.

Comment: Screenshot of https://tweakers.net/categorie/216/beamers/producten/ (a price comparision site, selected beamer) showing many beamers with other resolutions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TqXR2.png

Comment: Daniel B, I am not saying I don't see other resolutions. I was asking about the resolutions between 1080p and 4K seen in the wiki image linked in my original question. I see the lower resolutions for business projectors you are talking of.

Answer (score 0):

> Just curious, if not, then what are these other resolutions used for?

Short answer:
They are used to display more on the screen.

Long answer:
Beamers come in all sort of resolutions. 640x480 was a classic one which matched nicely with VGA monitors. You would see the same via the beamer as on screen. As resolutions become higher on computers so did beamer resolutions.

Beamer used in business environment nicely scaled up to these newer resolutions.  At home beamer were not commonly used, and if they were used it was often to project a movie or as TV screen. This leads to a lot of beamer with 'weird' resolutions like 1080p.

With the movie to 4K you see a high end beamer with 4K-ish resolutions.
(4K-ish since classic 4K is 4096×2160 and movies are often UHD (3840×2160)).

> What are these other resolutions used for?

Simply to put more on the screen/projection, or to have a finer resolution for a better picture. For current movies that does not help, especially not if they need to be upscaled. But if you want to project a lot of spreadsheets in a readable format then these intermediate resolutions are very welcome.